# Java TreeSet<int[]>: duplicate elements?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I want to have some pairs of int in a TreeSet, and sort them by the first number.

Code [test here](http://ideone.com/sN1th7):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    SortedSet<int[]> s = new TreeSet<int[]>(new Comparator<int[]>(){
        public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
            return b[0] - a[0];
        }
    });
    int[] a = new int[]{1, 2};
    int[] b = new int[]{1, 3};
    s.add(a);
    s.add(b);
    System.out.println(s.size());
}
```

I don't know why the size of TreeSet turns out to be 1. Seems like the hashCode of `a` and `b` are same, but why?

Thanks for any help.

BTW: in fact, I was trying to put duplicate numbers in a set, which is not possible. Then I tried to have int pairs in a set. The first number is the actual number I want, the second number was there to prevent duplication. But I run into this problem.

Comment: What were you thinking, brother, when you've done this  `return b[0] - a[0];` ?

Comment: Tree based Maps only use Comparable or Comparator's compareTo and compare method.Hashcode has no relevance in Tree data structures

Comment: @Meng Wang Check out the Javadocs I included in the answer

Comment: I saw it. Thanks! @KumarAbhinav

Comment: @alfasin I explained what I wanted to do in "BTW" part. That's why I use `b[0] - a[0]` as result of `compare()`. Now I know it's not doable. Thanks!

Comment: "put duplicate numbers in a set" is not only "no possible" - it beats the purpose of Set. Seems like another manifistation of the  [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common mistake to think that hashcode plays a role in Tree based data structure,it actually doesn't.Hash Based collections(`HashSet,LinkedHashSet,HashMap,LinkedHashMap` and few others ) use hashing along with equals to differentiate an Object.

In your case,a TreeSet,you are treating object equality using a comparator which considers equality based on length of array sizes.If two arrays have same size,it considers equal.So in your case,the array b replaces array a in the head node as both arrays have length 1.Even if you override `hashcode`,it won't be of any use.

**From JavaDocs:-**

***Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.***

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that Set/Map use `compare()` instead of `hashCode()` to tell equality of elements/keys. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out to be `1` because your `compare` method only uses the first number in the array, and the two arrays you have both begin with `1`. Therefore, from the point of view of the `TreeSet`, the two arrays are the same.

[TreeSet.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) returns

> true if this set did not already contain the specified element

, and since the two values are considered equal (`compare` returns `0`), the second value is not added and `add()` returns `false`

Comment: Might want to point out that [TreeSet.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29) returns "true if this set did not already contain the specified element", and since the two values are considered equals (`compare` returns 0), the second value is *not* added and `add()` returns `false`.

Comment: @Andreas Good thinking. Will you object if I just cut and paste your exact words?

Comment: *For complete answer:* Definition of a `Set` is "[a collection that contains no duplicate elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)". If you don't want duplicates eliminated, don't use a `Set`. You'd want a sorted "Bag", which in Java means a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that TreeSet uses `compare` method instead of `hashCode()` to tell the equality of elements. And also thanks for the suggestion of `PriorityQueue`. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @MengWang Not all `Set`s. `HashSet` uses `hashCode()` and `equals()`.You need to carefully read the documentation of any class before you use it.